# Not all items shown in GridBagLayout row

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am designing a panel to display items using a `GridBagLayout`. The result I am looking for is something like this:

[image]

However, currently I am seeing the following:

[image]

I then initialise my panel and set the layout:

```
JPanel surveyDetailsFieldsPane = new JPanel();  
surveyDetailsFieldsPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 300));
surveyDetailsFieldsPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410, 300));
GridBagLayout detailsGridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
surveyDetailsFieldsPane.setLayout(detailsGridBagLayout);
surveyDetailsFieldsPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(STANDARD_BORDER,
            STANDARD_BORDER,
            STANDARD_BORDER,
            STANDARD_BORDER));
```

I initialise my components to add to the grid:

```
JLabel jobNameLbl.setText("Job Name:");
JTextField jobNameTF = new JTextField(20);

JLabel jobNumLbl.setText("Job Number:");
JTextField jobNumTF = new JTextField(12);
```

Then I add components to the grid using the `addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid` method:

```
 // Row 1
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(jobNameLbl, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.NONE, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(jobNameTF, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
 // Row 2
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(jobNumLbl, 0, 1, 1, 1, 10, 0, GridBagConstraints.NONE, GridBagConstraints.WEST); 
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(jobNumTF, 1, 1, 0, 1, 40, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(dateLbl, 4, 1, 1, 1, 10, 0, GridBagConstraints.NONE, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(dateTF, 5, 1, 0, 1, 40, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
```

The method used is shown below:

```
private void addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(Component component, int gridX, int gridY,
                            int gridWidth, int gridHeight, int weightX, 
                            int weightY, int fill, int anchor) {

    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraint.gridx = gridX;
    constraint.gridy = gridY;
    constraint.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    constraint.gridheight = gridHeight;
    constraint.weightx = weightX;
    constraint.weighty = weightY;       
    constraint.fill = fill;
    constraint.anchor = anchor;
    constraint.insets = new Insets(Dimens.SMALL_BORDER, 
                                Dimens.SMALL_BORDER, 
                                Dimens.SMALL_BORDER, 
                                Dimens.SMALL_BORDER);
    detailsGridBagLayout.setConstraints(component, constraint);
    surveyDetailsFieldsPane.add(component);
}
```

Please let me know what I have done wrong here!

Comment: gridbaglayout is very tricky i think, thats why i switched to formlayout from jgoodies. i guess it has something to do with your `weightx`and how you created your grid

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What's wrong with the provided drawing?

Comment: What's wrong with your attention span? Can't it last to the *end of the **sentence***? Where is the MCVE / SSCCE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Not sure what the need for rudeness is, I'm just trying to clarify what's wrong so I can edit my post appropriately. Why does my image need more width and height? As for the MCVE I felt that my provided code was not excessive and covers all that needs to be shown to anyone answering the question. Please let me know how it could be improved. Thanks.

Comment: What @AndrewThompson meant with a [mcve] (if you read the links) is that you need to create a NEW, complete project that we can copy-paste including a `main` method and the imports, so we don't have to guess or write it on our own, since well... you're the one needing help, you should be the one doing that extra effort into making this new program that shows your problem... regarding the image, Andrew was saying what would happen if you shorten or enlarge the GUI, what would the TextFields do? Should they "crop"? Or should they get shorter? The same if you enlarge the GUI...

Comment: @Frakcool Thanks for the info. If I don't figure it out soon I'll rewrite my post. Otherwise I will close the question.

Comment: It's always better to rewrite, you have almost 300 rep, you're still learning how the site works, but the [mcve] is crucial in every question you make. Good luck, once you edit your post including pertinent code that demonstrates the issue, you can then tag me back or Andrew :)

Comment: @Frakcool Much appreciated. I figured out my issue with this and have written another question, taking on board your advice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527569/components-not-displaying-in-jscrollpane). I hope it is an improvement over this one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it will solve your problem but:

```
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(jobNumLbl, 0, 1, 1, 1, 10, 0, ...
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(jobNumTF, 1, 1, 0, 1, 40, 0, ...
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(dateLbl, 4, 1, 1, 1, 10, 0, ...
 addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(dateTF, 5, 1, 0, 1, 40, 0, ...
```

Your gridx values are 0, 1, 4, 5.

You can't just try to add a component to grid 4. The GridBagLayout doesn't magically add components to grids 2 and 3. So you need to add the components to grid 2 and 3.

If you want the jobname text field to occupy the space of the 3 components under it, then you need to specify a gridwidth value of 3 when you add the jobname text field.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The tutorial will explain how the gridwidth parameter works and provides a working example for you to download and test.