# Components not displaying in JScrollPane

Tags: java, jpanel, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I am adding components to a `JPanel` which uses the `GridBagLayout`. I'm then adding this `JPanel` to a `JScrollPane`, and then adding this to a `JPanel` with a titled border. However, the panel appears blank when I run my application - where have the components gone?

```
public class Main {

    static JPanel surveyDetailsFieldsPane;
    static JScrollPane surveyDetailsScrollPane;
    static JPanel surveyDetailsTitledPane;
    static GridBagLayout detailsGBL;

    static JLabel lblJobName;
    static JTextField txtJobName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 300));

        initComponents();
        initFieldsPanel();
        initScrollPane();
        initTitledPane();
        addComponentsToPanel();

        surveyDetailsScrollPane.add(surveyDetailsFieldsPane);
        surveyDetailsTitledPane.add(surveyDetailsScrollPane);
        f.add(surveyDetailsTitledPane);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void initComponents() {

        lblJobName = new JLabel("Job Name:");
        txtJobName = new JTextField(20);
    }

    private static void initFieldsPanel() {

        surveyDetailsFieldsPane = new JPanel();
        detailsGBL = new GridBagLayout();
        surveyDetailsFieldsPane.setLayout(detailsGBL);
    }

    private static void initScrollPane() {

        surveyDetailsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    }

    private static void initTitledPane() {

        surveyDetailsTitledPane = new JPanel();
        surveyDetailsTitledPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        surveyDetailsTitledPane.setBorder(createTitledBorder("Survey Details"));
    }

    private static void addComponentsToPanel() {

        addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(lblJobName, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.NONE, GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START);
        addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(txtJobName, 2, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
    }

    private static void addComponentToSurveyDetailsGrid(Component component, int gridX, int gridY,
                            int gridWidth, int gridHeight, int weightX, 
                            int weightY, int fill, int anchor) {

        GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraint.gridx = gridX;
        constraint.gridy = gridY;
        constraint.gridwidth = gridWidth;
        constraint.gridheight = gridHeight;
        constraint.weightx = weightX;
        constraint.weighty = weightY;       
        constraint.fill = fill;
        constraint.anchor = anchor;
        constraint.insets = new Insets(5, 
                                5, 
                                5, 
                                5);
        detailsGBL.setConstraints(component, constraint);
        surveyDetailsFieldsPane.add(component);
    }
}
```

If I add the `surveyDetailsFieldsPane` directly to the `JFrame`, I see the components displayed as such:

[image]

But otherwise the frame is blank (save for the vertical scroll bar and titled border):

[image]

Please let me know why I can't see my components within the `JScrollPane` and how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `JScrollPane#add`, use `JScrollPane#setViewportView` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer Simple things.... Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I like simple problems :)